# Convert strings of either one date or possibly two, to the correct number of Java date instances

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I have the following possible string patterns (whitespace is variable):

```
2-4 Jun
8-11 Jun
8 Jun-11 Jun
20-Jun
28 Jun-01 Jul
15-18 Jun
```

and I want to convert to Java dates, either one or two.

Any regex shortcuts ? Iam migrating a legacy excel spreadsheet if it makes a difference, the column is not formatted)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @ndtreviv well no not really. I know how to create java dates.

Comment: I voted to close, but didn't pay enough attention. Here some dates are a bit more complicated (15-18 jun). @NimChimpsky you should clarify that.

Comment: @ColinHebert Have changed the title to emphasize the specific patterns.

Comment: @ColinHebert - Good call. I definitely wasn't paying enough attention! NimChimpsky - sorry, SimpleDateFormat enables you to parse a date from a string, but you have to know the format first, which is where regex comes in, which is where you question actually sits. Is the permutation of possibilities limited?

Comment: @ndtreviv to the patterns I listed, yes.

Comment: Is that all test data? So 30-Jun-2-Jul or so is not possible?

Comment: @user802421 yes that is possible, have updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, here is a snippet that should do it or at least give you the basics:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)-(\\d+)?\\s*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)").matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.groupCount()==3) {
        int first = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        int second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
        String month = m.group(3);
        // DO something here
    } else {
        int first = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        String month = m.group(2);
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but you changed your question and added some more cases. Anyway, the basic idea is to play with capturing groups (using '(' and ')'), non capturing groups (using '(?:' and ')'), quantifiers ('?'=0 or 1, '*'=0, 1 or more, '+' at least 1. And the logical OR-operator '|'

Comment: For all the details of regexp, look at the `Pattern` Javadoc.